# Is there one word for tenure in official committees (whether appointed or elected)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for office as appointed or elected member in national councils or committees?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What do you find lacking with your own suggestion, *tenure*?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7709/142322) regarding single word requests.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could ***charge*** be helpful for you?

> An assigned duty or task; a responsibility: The commission's charge was to determine the facts.

From Free Dictionary

Comment: Until the OP clarifies, we're just guessing at the question.